# mysql - capture last error and insert it in log table. @@errror_count?

Tags: mysql

I have an automated process that runs a sql command, and right after it I capture a couple things for a log table.  I would also like to capture if the process had any errors and I can not figure out how to do that.

-- this is the statement that sometimes has errors

INSERT INTO etc...

-- and this is what I want to use to track the results of the statement

Insert into log_table(run_time, row_count, **error_count**)
select now(), row_count(), **???**    ;

is there a system variable I can look at, similar to row_count(), that will give me the number of errors with my last transaction?

I tried @@error_count but it always seems to be 1, regardless if the last transaction was successful or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds a bit like a [xy-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can get what I need from row_count(), which will have a value of -1 when there is one or more errors with the previous dml statement.